# Android debug build stuck on Waiting for observatory port to be available

Tags: android, flutter

I have application packagename `com.wikitude.fluttersamples`

As for release build

```
flutter clean
flutter build apk
adb install build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

It works well.

As for debug build

```
flutter run -d R -v
```

it stuck in

`[        ] Waiting for observatory port to be available...`

```
[   +3 ms] Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
[   +2 ms] executing: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/wikitude-flutter-plugin-examples-master/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[  +11 ms] Exit code 0 from: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/wikitude-flutter-plugin-examples-master/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="10" (Raw: "10")
               A: package="com.wikitude.fluttersamples" (Raw: "com.wikitude.fluttersamples")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: platformBuildVersionName="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x15
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: uses-permission (line=15)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.CAMERA" (Raw: "android.permission.CAMERA")
               E: uses-permission (line=16)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION")
               E: uses-permission (line=17)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
               E: uses-permission (line=18)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=19)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=20)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
               E: uses-feature (line=22)
                 A: android:glEsVersion(0x01010281)=(type 0x11)0x20000
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
               E: uses-feature (line=25)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.hardware.camera" (Raw: "android.hardware.camera")
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
               E: uses-feature (line=28)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.hardware.location" (Raw: "android.hardware.location")
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
               E: uses-feature (line=31)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" (Raw: "android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer")
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
               E: uses-feature (line=34)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.hardware.sensor.compass" (Raw: "android.hardware.sensor.compass")
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
               E: uses-feature (line=37)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" (Raw: "android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope")
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
               E: application (line=47)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="Flutter Examples" (Raw: "Flutter Examples")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: meta-data (line=53)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" (Raw: "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="AIzaSyAGupFZYj4vdYOcdWKURHGgLtsb3S6PyzE" (Raw: "AIzaSyAGupFZYj4vdYOcdWKURHGgLtsb3S6PyzE")
                 E: activity (line=57)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x400037b4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=71)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame" (Raw:
                     "io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=75)
                     E: action (line=76)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=78)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=82)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.ar.core" (Raw: "com.google.ar.core")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="optional" (Raw: "optional")
                 E: activity (line=86)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.wikitude.architect.BrowserActivity" (Raw: "com.wikitude.architect.BrowserActivity")
                 E: activity (line=87)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.wikitude.tools.activities.MediaPlayerActivity" (Raw:
                   "com.wikitude.tools.activities.MediaPlayerActivity")
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x4a0
                 E: uses-library (line=90)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="org.apache.http.legacy" (Raw: "org.apache.http.legacy")
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: activity (line=93)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x103023a
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity" (Raw: "com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:excludeFromRecents(0x01010017)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x4a0
                 E: meta-data (line=100)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version" (Raw: "com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0xac70498
                 E: activity (line=104)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x1030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: meta-data (line=109)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.version" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=@0x7f060000
[   +2 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on SM G975F.
[        ] executing: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s R58M20JNSQB shell am force-stop com.wikitude.fluttersamples
[ +119 ms] executing: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s R58M20JNSQB shell pm list packages com.wikitude.fluttersamples
[  +79 ms] package:com.wikitude.fluttersamples
[   +3 ms] executing: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s R58M20JNSQB shell cat /data/local/tmp/sky.com.wikitude.fluttersamples.sha1
[  +32 ms] 1b94ef462bd0e6c9bad260dd4c2d72ca23df661e
[        ] Latest build already installed.
[        ] SM G975F startApp
[   +2 ms] executing: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s R58M20JNSQB shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez
enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true
com.wikitude.fluttersamples/com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity
[ +161 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[        ] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```

then I use logcat and check the log.
Here I can see some doubtful logs

```
12-28 00:11:20.577  5782 19748 W ActivityManager: crash : com.wikitude.fluttersamples,0
12-28 00:11:20.583  5782 19748 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity
12-28 00:11:20.651  3824  6501 D AppErrorNotification: errorType : 24, process : com.wikitude.fluttersamples , uid : 0
```

Full log

```
1|beyond2:/ $ logcat | grep flutter                                                                                                                        
12-28 00:10:44.250  5782 21942 I ActivityManager: Killing 6201:com.wikitude.fluttersamples/u0a410 (adj 900): crash
12-28 00:10:44.256  5276  7912 E BufferQueueProducer: [Application Error: com.wikitude.fluttersamples#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
12-28 00:10:44.262  5782  5811 D ViewRootImpl@7b4956a[fluttersamples]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
12-28 00:10:44.263  5782  5811 D ViewRootImpl@7b4956a[fluttersamples]: Surface release. android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie:7967 android.view.ViewRootImpl.die:7935 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked:497 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView:435 android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate:124 android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog:518 android.app.Dialog.dismiss:501 com.android.server.am.AppErrorDialog.dismiss:181 
12-28 00:10:44.263  5782  5811 V WindowManager: Remove Window{c0e67c2 u0 Application Error: com.wikitude.fluttersamples}: mSurfaceController=Surface(name=Application Error: com.wikitude.fluttersamples)/@0x59e504b mAnimatingExit=false mRemoveOnExit=false mHasSurface=true surfaceShowing=true isAnimationSet=false app-animation=false mWillReplaceWindow=false inPendingTransaction=false mDisplayFrozen=false callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2732 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:1939 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:268 android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow:4537 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie:7967 android.view.ViewRootImpl.die:7935 
12-28 00:10:44.264  5782  5811 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Application Error: com.wikitude.fluttersamples)/@0x59e504b called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:1903 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:838 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeImmediately:2711 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2861 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2732 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:1939 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:268 android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow:4537 
12-28 00:10:44.264  5276  7912 I SurfaceFlinger: id=70610 Removed Application Error: com.wikitude.fluttersamples#0 (0/158)
12-28 00:10:44.267  5276  5276 I Layer   : id=70610 onRemoved Application Error: com.wikitude.fluttersamples#0 
12-28 00:10:44.275  5276  7912 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: c0e67c2 Application Error: com.wikitude.fluttersamples#0
12-28 00:10:44.277  5782  5811 V WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{c0e67c2 u0 Application Error: com.wikitude.fluttersamples} to Window{4520dfd u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2867 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2732 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:1939 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:268 
12-28 00:10:44.282  5782  5820 D WindowManager: reportFocusChangedSerialized, focused=false, inTouchMode=true, win=Window{c0e67c2 u0 Application Error: com.wikitude.fluttersamples}
12-28 00:10:44.292  5276  5276 I Layer   : id=70609 onRemoved c0e67c2 Application Error: com.wikitude.fluttersamples#0 
12-28 00:11:19.748  5782 19790 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.wikitude.fluttersamples appid=10410 user=0: from pid 6468 caller com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runForceStop:967 
12-28 00:11:19.767  5782 19790 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.wikitude.fluttersamples appid=10410 user=150: from pid 6468 caller com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runForceStop:967 
12-28 00:11:19.784  5782  5782 D SamsungAlarmManager: Remove alarm for next reason : android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED : package: com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:19.799  5782  5810 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED dat=package:com.wikitude.fluttersamples flg=0x10 (has extras) } to android/com.kddi.android.CpaNotiReceiver
12-28 00:11:19.986  5782 19790 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.RUN typ=null flg=0x30000000 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.wikitude.fluttersamples/com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity}} from uid 2000
12-28 00:11:19.986  5782 19790 I ActivityManager: [IOP] sourceDir : /data/app/com.wikitude.fluttersamples-a2PGq_Fwb4Hg447If5UKaA== in ActivityStacksupervisor
12-28 00:11:20.044  5276  5276 I SurfaceFlinger: id=70621 createSurf (6080x6080),2 flag=4, AppWindowToken{81cfc4c token=Token{66cf47f ActivityRecord{babb19e u0 com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity t4164}}}#0
12-28 00:11:20.055  5782 19790 D StorageManagerService: getExternalStorageMountMode : final mountMode=1, uid : 10410, packageName : com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:20.056  5782 19790 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted:com.wikitude.fluttersamples user:0
12-28 00:11:20.056  5782 19790 D ActivityManager: package  com.wikitude.fluttersamples, user - 0 is SDcard whitelisted
12-28 00:11:20.056  5782 19790 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.wikitude.fluttersamples user:0
12-28 00:11:20.056  5782 19790 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.wikitude.fluttersamples user:0
12-28 00:11:20.073  5782  5782 D GameManagerService: MultiWindowEventListener.onFocusStackChanged(), state=0, top=ComponentInfo{com.wikitude.fluttersamples/com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity}
12-28 00:11:20.094  5782  5812 I ActivityManager: Start proc 6480:com.wikitude.fluttersamples/u0a410 for activity com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity
12-28 00:11:20.101  6480  6480 I .fluttersample: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-28 00:11:20.138  5782 19790 I ActivityManager: DSS on for com.wikitude.fluttersamples and scale is 1.0
12-28 00:11:20.180  5782 19790 D GamePkgDataHelper: notifyAppCreate(), pkgName: com.wikitude.fluttersamples, sendRet: true
12-28 00:11:20.180  5782 19144 D GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:20.180  5782 19144 D GameManagerService: handleMessage(), MSG_APP_CREATE. ignore. pkgName: com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:20.186  5782 19790 D GamePkgDataHelper: getSosPolicy(). com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:20.187  5782 19790 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.wikitude.fluttersamples, mCurrentUserId: 0, callerUserId: 0
12-28 00:11:20.187  5782 19790 D GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:20.187  5782 19790 D GameManagerService: noteResumeComponent(), resumeComponent: com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:20.187  5782 19144 D GameManagerService: handleForegroundChange(). pkgName: com.wikitude.fluttersamples, clsName: com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity,FgActivityName:com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity,userID:0
12-28 00:11:20.187  5782 19144 D GameManagerService:   handleForegroundChange(). set mFgApp: com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:20.190  5782 19790 D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.wikitude.fluttersamples, userId = 0
12-28 00:11:20.190  5782 21694 D GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgDataIncServer(). com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:20.214  5782  5811 D CodecSolution: isMaxAspectPackageEx: com.wikitude.fluttersamples : false(0)
12-28 00:11:20.215  5782  5811 D CodecSolution: isMaxAspectPackageEx: com.wikitude.fluttersamples : false(0)
12-28 00:11:20.217  5782 21694 D GamePkgDataHelper: getSosPolicy(). com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:20.228  5782 21694 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.wikitude.fluttersamples, mCurrentUserId: 0, callerUserId: 0
12-28 00:11:20.229  5782 21694 D GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:20.242  6480  6480 I .fluttersample: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
12-28 00:11:20.319 19925 19925 D KNOXCORE::LockSecureFolderTask: ResumedActivity userId0[com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity]
12-28 00:11:20.322  5782 19677 D MdnieScenarioControlService:  packageName : com.wikitude.fluttersamples    className : com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity
12-28 00:11:20.566  6480  6480 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.wikitude.fluttersamples, PID: 6480
12-28 00:11:20.566  6480  6480 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.wikitude.fluttersamples-a2PGq_Fwb4Hg447If5UKaA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.wikitude.fluttersamples-a2PGq_Fwb4Hg447If5UKaA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.wikitude.fluttersamples-a2PGq_Fwb4Hg447If5UKaA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
12-28 00:11:20.566  6480  6480 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.startInitialization(FlutterMain.java:138)
12-28 00:11:20.566  6480  6480 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.startInitialization(FlutterMain.java:110)
12-28 00:11:20.566  6480  6480 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication.onCreate(FlutterApplication.java:22)
12-28 00:11:20.577  5782 19748 W ActivityManager: crash : com.wikitude.fluttersamples,0
12-28 00:11:20.583  5782 19748 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity
12-28 00:11:20.651  3824  6501 D AppErrorNotification: errorType : 24, process : com.wikitude.fluttersamples , uid : 0
12-28 00:11:20.710  5782  5810 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{babb19e u0 com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity t4164 f}
12-28 00:11:20.730  5782  5810 I WindowManager: Cancelling animation restarting=false, leash=null, surface=Surface(name=AppWindowToken{81cfc4c token=Token{66cf47f ActivityRecord{babb19e u0 com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity t4164}}})/@0xaa7e967, parent=Surface(name=Task=4164)/@0xf45f314
12-28 00:11:20.744 20419 24935 I AppIconSolution: return adaptive icon for com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:20.772  5276  7912 I SurfaceFlinger: id=70621 Removed AppWindowToken{81cfc4c token=Token{66cf47f ActivityRecord{babb19e u0 com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity t4164}}}#0 (0/154)
12-28 00:11:20.783  5276  5276 I Layer   : id=70621 onRemoved AppWindowToken{81cfc4c token=Token{66cf47f ActivityRecord{babb19e u0 com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity t4164}}}#0 
12-28 00:11:20.831  5782  7760 I ActivityManager: Process com.wikitude.fluttersamples (pid 6480) has died: cch  CEM (404,2131)
12-28 00:11:21.575  5782 19144 D GameManagerService: handleForegroundChange(). pkgName: com.wikitude.fluttersamples, clsName: com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity,FgActivityName:com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity,userID:0
12-28 00:11:21.575  5782 19144 D GameManagerService:   handleForegroundChange(). set mFgApp: com.wikitude.fluttersamples
12-28 00:11:21.766  3824  6501 V FasUtils: There is com.wikitude.fluttersamples [10410] in FAS table
12-28 00:11:21.811  3824  6501 V AppErrorNotification: Filtered due to 1day concept : com.wikitude.fluttersamples / uid : 10410
```

`flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F203, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at /Users/whitebear/flutter_v1.9
    • Framework revision 68587a0916 (4 months ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.0, Build version 11A420a
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.5

[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.35.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.2.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G975F • R58M20JNSQB • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
```